# Generating a module adds an extra slash to the path in app.module.ts

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli

I'm curious why the generator in Angular CLI tools adds an extra slash character for modules. When I execute

> ng generate component visual

the following line is added to *app.module.ts* file

```
import { VisualComponent } from './visual/visual.component';
```

but when I execute

> ng generate module visual --flat --module=app

as suggested on [Angular official site](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt5#add-the-approutingmodule) I get a bit different syntax like this

```
import { AppRoutingModule } from './/app-routing.module';
```

and I can't figure out what the extra slash is good for. I wonder if I'm doing something wrong, if my system is set up in an unexpected way for the CLI tools or if it's simply a bug in the generator that's going to be corrected in a future version.

Comment: It is completely useless. You do not need it but it works too.

Comment: @LucasRosenberger "*You do not need i but...*"? I'm not sure I follow.

Comment: @LucasRosenberger Oh, I just realized what you mean. You meant that I don't need **it**, right? Why is it being added in the first place? Some Unix convention that spills over to my Win machine?

Comment: Yeah. I do not know why it is being added ¯\_(ツ)_/¯.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> and I can't figure out what the extra slash is good for.

It is useless and can be ignored. Seems like a bug worth reporting, or updating the toolchain to make sure its not there in the latest versions.

Comment: How do I report the bug to the Angular team?